# Data-icon not working in tidesdk

Tags: html, web, tidesdk

The following line has no effect in tidesdk,though its working fine in chrome and firefox

```
<span class="icon-font" aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#xe009;"></span>
```

I want that line to show up icon-images so that I don't have to use images.Is there any workaround or is it supported and I am doing something wrong?